# Check if a date falls between two dates in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with city, class (class 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), start date and end date. I have a web application (PHP) that I need to check to see if the class matches in a date range.

So for example, demo table:

```
City    Class      StartDate      EndDate
LA      1          2019-09-13    2019-10-29
SF      2          2019-09-13    2019-10-29
```

I need to query this database to check if the city, class matches the date falls in-between those dates.

Is there a way I can do this with MySQL and then pass it back to PHP? How would I go about doing this?

I am able to query MySQL this way to return the row:

```
SELECT * FROM blackout where '2019-09-13' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND city="SF" AND class="2";
```

But I am looking for more of a binary true or false return.

Comment: `sf` and `SF` are most likely 2 different animals.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I will update my example.

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`. This will return `0` (false) if there are no matches, non-zero (true) if there are any matches.

Comment: Also see the “EXISTS” SQL keyword which can be MUCH FASTER than a naive count in some cases. If the count is returned to the application (eg. cannot be short-circuited in the database) then the DB might access many more rows trying to resolve a value that has no use past 0/not-0.

Comment: To the guy who posted EXISTS, I have it working like that, works like a charm. If you want to post a answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of

```
      SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *
       FROM blackout where '2019-09-13' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
       AND city="SF" AND class="2");
```

is **1**

And for

```
      SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *
       FROM blackout where '2017-09-13' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
       AND city="SF" AND class="2");
```

You get an **0**

Answer (score 0):

try this query for your solution

```sql
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') AS result FROM blackout WHERE (date(start_date) >= "2019-09-03" AND date(end_date) <= "2019-09-03") AND city="SF" AND class="2";
```

hope this may help you.
let me know if you face any issue.